# neovim: use new .vimrc and .vim

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I wanted to take a look into neovim coming from vim and my question is about the `.vimrc`/`.viminfo` as well as the `.vim` folder. Preferably I would like to use fresh instances of these.

Do I have to create them by myself or will neovim create them? I don't want to link them together and like the idea of a ***reset***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neovim dosn't use .vimrc/.viminfo as well as the .vim folder.

For Neovim:

- Use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim` instead of `.vimrc` for storing
  configuration.
- Use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim` instead of `.vim` to store configuration
  files.
- Use `$XDG_DATA_HOME/shada/main.shada` instead of `.viminfo` for
  persistent session information.